# OnAction on a custom ribbon button

Tags: excel, vba, ribbon

This is the XML fragment I have in my Excel Workbook, It displays correctly in my ribbon, custom icons and text, but when I click on the icon I can't get the Sub "OpenSettings" running. My subs are in the WorkBook, not in a separate module...

```
        <group id="customGroup3" label="Settings">
                <button id="button5" label="Manage Settings" size="large" onAction="OpenSettings" image="Info" />

            </group>
```

what do I need to add to Sub name to make it working?
I have tried "ThisDocument.OpenSettings" with no luck

Comment: Have you tried putting it in standard code module instead of Workbook code module?  Also, it might not hurt to include the code for your `OpenSettings` routine.

Comment: The problem is I have already developed all my code in thw WorkBook code module. I need someting to call my Workbook code form a module.

Comment: the OpenSetting routines simply calls a form to edit soem settings...and simply does "frmSettings.Show (vbModal)"

Comment: Have you tried applying the ribbon to a custom callback? -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942866.aspx

Comment: if the callback is in a Module, it works correctly, but doesn't work if my Sub is in my WorkBook...

Comment: *I have already developed all my code in thw WorkBook code module* ,-- So, cut and paste it from the workbook module to a standard module.

Comment: *doesn't work if my Sub is in my WorkBook..*  Sounds like you have solved the problem.  Put the sub in a standard module.

Comment: No, because if I simply cut/paste all my code form WorkBook to Module, it doesn't work anymore....

I solved my problem by simply creating a Sub in my module that calls ThisWorkbook.MySub on turn. 

Everything is OK now....

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your XML to:

```
<group id="customGroup3" label="Settings"> 
  <button id="button5" label="Manage Settings" size="large" onAction="launch_OpenSettings" image="Info" />
</group>
```

Try adding this code to new module in your workbook:

```
Sub launch_OpenSettings(control As IRibbonControl)
  Call OpenSettings
End Sub
```

Every button need to have Callbacks  (these can be generate in the Custom UI tool):[image]